# how to limit the data that is being fetched from a csv?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using google colab working on the TSNE. I have used google drive and mounted it and i am trying to read the reviews csv file.

Below is the code i am using. However it is running for the entire dataset. How can i put a limit of 5000? For the `read_sql_query` method in pandas we can directly limit it. But how can we do in google colab ipynb file.?

Code:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Reviews.csv') 
# filtering only positive and negative reviews i.e. not taking into consideration those reviews with Score=3
# SELECT * FROM Reviews WHERE Score != 3 LIMIT 500000, will give top 500000 data points
# you can change the number to any other number based on your computing power
# filtered_data = pd.read_sql_query(""" SELECT * FROM Reviews WHERE Score != 3 LIMIT 500000""", con) 

df_bonus = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Reviews.csv')

filtered_data = df_bonus[df_bonus['Score']!=3]
```

i tried like these ways

```
filtered_data = df_bonus[df_bonus['Score']!=3] limit 5000
```

it did not work. I tried like this as well

```
filtered_data = df_bonus[(df_bonus['Score']!=3) limit 5000]
```

Nothing works. Any Help?

How do i filter for about 5000 reviews so that i can run the file faster?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for ```pandas.read_csv```. There is an ```nrows``` parameter.

Comment: What has the `sqlite3.connect()` command to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df = pd.read_csv(file_path, chunksize=chunk_size)` to read a large file in batches. Then, just loop it while aggregating each batch desired rows to some DataFrame until you have enough rows:

```
#initialize empty DataFrame results
for batch in df:
    filtered_data = batch[batch['Score']!=3]
    #add filtered_data to results
    #if results is big enough break
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to read in 5000

```
chunks = pd.read_csv('Reviews.csv', chunksize=5000)
```

If you want to read in more but are having memory issues try this.
Reduce or increase the chunk size depending on your RAM availability.

```
chunks = pd.read_csv('Reviews.csv', chunksize=5000)
i = 0
chunk_list = []
for chunk in chunks:
    i += 1
    chunk_list.append(chunk)
    df = pd.concat(chunk_list, sort = True)
```

If this doesnt work. Try this:

```
chunks = pd.read_csv('Reviews.csv', chunksize=10000)
i = 0
chunk_list = []
for chunk in chunks:
    if i >= 10:
        break
    i += 1
    chunk_list.append(chunk)
    df1 = pd.concat(chunk_list, sort = True)


chunks = pd.read_csv('Reviews.csv', skiprows = 100000, chunksize=10000)
i = 0
chunk_list = []
for chunk in chunks:
    if i >= 10:
        break
    i += 1
    chunk_list.append(chunk)
    df2 = pd.concat(chunk_list, sort = True)


d3 = pd.concat([d1,d2], sort = True)
```

skiprows was calculated by how many rows the previous dataframe has read in.
This will break after 10 chunks is loaded. store this as df1. and read in the file again by starting at chunk 11, and append that again.

Comment: It did not work. I have used the nrows attribute while reading the csv and have limited to 5000. Now i was able to run it .

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the pandas documentation for the read_csv method in pandas. The attribute nrows is the one where we have to pass the number of rows we want to read.

`df = pd.read_csv(file_path, nrows=5000`